# Redirecting API call to a dockerized node-express server with nginx

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I have a node-express server running inside a dockerized container with **expose port 3001**. My nginx is installed on OS with **sudo apt install nginx**. What I want is everytime a call is made to app.domain.com:3001 I want to redirect that call to **localhost:3001**.I am new to nginx configuration. I would prefer I could do the same with *.conf file in conf.d folder of nginx.Also the response of API should have same domain **.domain.com** so that I can set **httpOnly** **cookies** on a angular app running on **app.domain.com**
My node docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  container1:
    image: node:18.12-alpine
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    container_name: container1
    depends_on:
      - container_mongodb
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "$APP_PORT:$APP_PORT"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - network1
    command: ./wait-for.sh container_mongodb:$MONGO_PORT -- npm run dev
  container_mongodb:
    image: mongo:6.0.3
    container_name: container_mongodb
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "$MONGO_EXPOSE_PORT:$MONGO_PORT"
    volumes:
      - container_mongodb_data:/data/db
      - ./src/config/auth/mongodb.key:/data/mongodb.key
    networks:
      - network1
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        cp /data/mongodb.key /data/mongodb.copy.key
        chmod 400 /data/mongodb.copy.key
        chown 999:999 /data/mongodb.copy.key
        exec docker-entrypoint.sh $$@
    command: ["mongod", "--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--keyFile", "/data/mongodb.copy.key"]
networks:
  network1:
    external: true

volumes:
  container_mongodb_data:
```

Comment: What do you actually want to happen when someone visits your site; do you actually want their browser address bar to change to `http://localhost:3001` and to try to contact a server running on the same system as the browser; or do you want to forward (not redirect) the request to the container?  You don't really seem to be using Docker's image system or network layer, could you install Node and MongoDB on the host the same way you do Nginx?

Comment: Well forwarding the request to container will also work, but will I be able to do SSL with let's encrypt? And no I don't want to change thier address bar to localhost. It should remain app.domain.com. And yes installing node and mongo on host is an option, but their are multiple microservices running on same docker network which are talking to each other. I will have to make a lot of changes to architecture. I don't want to do that unless this method is not feasible